# Get singleton of unknown implementing class without if-statments?

Tags: java, interface, singleton, implementation

I want to be able to call `getInstance()` of an **unknown implementing class**. Is writing if-statements the only solution? See the class `Main`.

```
public interface Soup{public Something getSomething();}

public class ChickenSoup implements Soup {
  private static ChickenSoup instance;
  public static ChickenSoup getInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new ChickenSoup();
    }
    return instance;
  }
  public Something getSomething(){return Something something;}
}

public class OnionSoup implements Soup {
  private static OnionSoup instance;
  public static OnionSoup getInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new OnionSoup();
    }
    return instance;
  }
  public Something getSomething(){
    Something something = somethingElse;
    return something;
  }
}

public class Main{
  private HashMap<String,Soup> soups;
  public Main(){
    buildMap();
  }
  public void callSoupClassGetInstance(String someSoupClassName){
    for (String impClass : soups.values()){
        if (someSoupClassName.contentEquals(impClass.simpleName())){
        //?????????????????????????????????????????
```

Here I want to be able to get the instance of the implementing class, but I can't because I have to be able to KNOW what I'm casting it to and cast it before I call `getInstance()`.
Can I do this without making a bunch of if statments to check the implementing class name?
In other words, is the only solution?:

```
   if (impClass.simpleName().contentEquals("OnionSoup")){
      OnionSoup.getInstance();
    }

private void buildMap(){
  soups = new HashMap<>();
  //(soupClassNames map) Code here that gets the Soup implementation 
  //class names by iterating class names in the package.
  for (String impClass : soupClassNames.values()){
    Class soupClass = Class.forName(impClass);
    soups.add(soupClassName,soupClass);
  }
```

Comment: Well you could do it with reflection... Note that your implementations aren't thread-safe, by the way.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about how to "do it with reflection"? I've tried using cast() and getMethod() to no avail. And getNewInstance() isn't what I need. Any ideas? (I'm a noob. We haven't got to thread-safe programming in my course yet. )

Comment: `getMethod()` is what you want. You should be more specific about what you've tried, and what happened :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll spend some time finding out how to use getMethod(). I must have been doing something wrong. At least I know where to look now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Reflections like this to invoke a static method of a class you have its name for.

```
try {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName( "OnionSoup" );
    Method method = clazz.getMethod("getInstance");
    method.invoke(null);
} catch( ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException |  IllegalAccessException |InvocationTargetException |SecurityException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I must be incredibly thick because I still don't quite understand.

Comment: How do I then assign the return value to a variable? I can't write
       OnionSoup onionSoup = method.invoke(null);
because I don't know what implementing class I've got. And the only way I know of is to put in a series of if statements.

Comment: What is is it that you dont understand? You get a class by name and call a method on it by name. Use this in your for loop with all your soup class names and all your getInstance methods will get invoked.

Comment: Yes you cannot assign the result of method.invoke to the right variable because you don't know of it in your for loop. You could assign it to your interface Soup s if thats what your want.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. It's not possible without if-statements (or switch, as I chose to use in the end). Assigning it to the interface was not what I needed. Even using a wildcard I couldn't invoke the method I needed.